# Hive connection to Kerberized Hadoop Cluster fails on weblogic platform in windows

Tags: windows, hadoop, weblogic, kerberos, impala

I have a problem on Windows weblogic server when I try to connect to Impala running on a kerberized Hadoop cluster.

I tried the connection with a small block of code in a stand-alone java code on my local machine and connected successfully.

```
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");

        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "D:\\hadoop\\security\\gss-jaas.conf");
        System.setProperty("sun.security.jgss.debug", "true");
        System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "D:\\hadoop\\security\\krb5.conf");


        String connUrl = "jdbc:hive2://***.***.**.***:21050/;principal=impala/host@REALM";

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connUrl);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Impala Connection Error" + e.getMessage());
    }
```

The connection was also successful on Linux weblogic server when I do a configuration in `startWeblogic.sh` file like **-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/appuser/security/gss-jaas.conf**

However when I try this code in my web application and deploy on weblogic in my Windows laptop, I get

```
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: GSS initiate failed
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.sendAndThrowMessage(TSaslTransport.java:232)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:316)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:52)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
```

I also added the path of `krb5.conf`, `gss-jaas.conf` and keytab file to the `startWeblogic.sh` but nothing changes.

I can make telnet connections from my local machine to the hadoop server 88, 21050 and 22 ports.

What is different on windows weblogic, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Enable the Kerberos debug traces with `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true` and also the _configuration_ debug traces with `-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext` -- then compare the traces between working and non-working cases.

Comment: Thank you so much Samson ! I could find the diffence by using your configuration advice. There was a difference between local and test in jass config files.